# Actuarial / Modelling question - difference between RUN date and VAL date

Tags: mathematical-modeling, actuarial-science

My understanding is that RUN date is the date you do the RUN (eg in prophet / moses / igloo / whatever, the date on which you *performed* the calculations)

Whereas VALuation date is the initial 'as at' date you use to VALue the run (eg using data extracted as it pertains to Year End / Month end whatever).

I have also heard that MODEL date is the date the model was built - so a model could be built on Monday (model date), run on tuesday (run date) but using the data 'as at' sunday (valuation date).

If you do work (or have worked) as an actuary, and / or have used the software applications above to develop models, I would be very interested in your views of exactly what the correct definitions are for the following:

- RUN date?
- Valuation date?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best place for this question. Maybe put it on money.stackexchange.com (also MSE by coincidence)?

Comment: I don't know what the actual tags fitting this question but [model-theory] and [valuation-theory] are not amongst them.

Comment: While @Asaf has corrected the tags for you, for future reference, many (but unfortunately not yet all) of the tags on this site have convenient tag-wikis, excerpts of which appear when you hover your mouse over the tag name. It is often a good idea to scan over the wiki to make sure the tag corresponds to the question you are asking.

Comment: What are you talking about?  Where are you seeing these words that you don't understand?

Comment: @graphth - I have updated the question to clarify, the issue with these 'words' is that they are given different meanings by different user communities.  Hence why I am looking for views from a very specific (and relevant) user group..

Comment: @RawFocus You can ask at Actuarial Outpost, a forum just for actuaries.  This forum has a very small percentage of people who have some experience/knowledge of actuaries.

Answer (score 1):

Model date is probably as you say, though this is unlikely to have a universally accepted definition.

Run date is the date - within the model - from which the model starts 'running' (projecting cash flows etc.)

Run date is therefore nothing to do with the date on which the run itself is carried out.

Valuation date is any date in respect of which a valuation is carried out by the model. A single run may include multiple valuation dates, usually the run date will be one of these but there may be others further in the future as well.